# poll() returns EINVAL for more than 256 descriptors on macOS

Tags: c, macos-sierra

Here is the example code that crashes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define POLL_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", OPEN_MAX);
    struct pollfd *poll_ = calloc(POLL_SIZE, sizeof(struct pollfd));
    if (poll(poll_, POLL_SIZE, -1) < 0)
        if (errno == EINVAL)
            perror("poll error");
    return 0;
}
```

If you set `POLL_SIZE` to 256 or less, the code works just fine. What's interesting is that if you run this code in Xcode, it executes normally, but if you run the binary yourself you get a crash.

The output is like this:

```
10240
poll error: Invalid argument
```

According to `poll(2)`:

```
[EINVAL] The nfds argument is greater than OPEN_MAX or the
         timeout argument is less than -1.
```

As you can see, `POLL_SIZE` is a lot smaller than the limit, and the timeout is exactly -1, yet it crashed.

My clang version that I use for manual building:

```
Configured with: prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Have you read [the manual page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/poll.2.html)? What does it say about `EINVAL`? What is the value of `OPEN_MAX`?

Comment: See also [getrlimit](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)

Comment: Actually, you'll often use `poll` with a not-too-big set of file descriptors, and mentioning several times -in the array passed to `poll`-  the *same* file descriptor (e.g. 0) is bad taste. So in practice it does not matter, and it is certainly a sysadmin issue. But read about [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if you make this into an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) have limits on resources. See e.g. [getrlimit](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getrlimit.2.html). You might change them (using `setrlimit`) and your sysadmin can also change them (e.g. configure these limits at startup or login time). There is a limit `RLIMIT_NOFILE` related to file descriptors. Read also about the `ulimit` [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins). See also [sysconf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with `_SC_OPEN_MAX`.

The [poll](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/poll.2.html) system call is given a not-too-big array, and it is bad taste (possible, but inefficient) to repeat some [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) in it. So in practice you'll often use it with a quite small array mentioning *different* (but valid) file descriptors. The second argument to `poll` is the number of useful entries (practically, all different), not the allocated size of the array.

You may deal with many file descriptors. Read about the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

BTW, your code is not crashing. `poll` is failing as documented (but not crashing).

You should read some POSIX programming book. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) is freely available, and most of it is on POSIX (not Linux specific) things.